# Flutter Firestore, where is the site that upload reference documents?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have seen official flutter firestore material only in pub.dev

But there even wasn't a single sentence about getDocuments().

Which site should I look at if I want to do a full formal study on this?

I have already seen cookbooks on flutter dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to study, there is even implementation on [API refrence](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html). However its just few lines, but I don't know what more there could be...

You can get there from package [main page,](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) on the right.

[image]

Comment: on main page, how do you enter the detail page?(pub.dev/documentation) I can`t find a button